# jackson fasterxml @JsonProperty not working

Tags: java, maven, jackson

I have a use case where I need to capitalize the first letter of my variable in Java,
I found out **@JsonProperty** is a possible solution for it,

**I added the following maven dependency -**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**And following is my code on how I used the annotation -**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Statement {
    @JsonProperty("Effect")
    private String Effect;

    @JsonProperty("Action")
    private String Action;

    @JsonProperty("Resource")
    private String Resource;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**For some reason it is not capitalising the first letters of my POJO variables ie. effect, action and resource.**

Comment: for the `setter` and `getter` to work the variable names should start with a lowercase, so change to `@JsonProperty("Effect")
    private String effect; public String getEffect () {...}`

Comment: That should work as it is. Can you show the Jackson code that serializes to JSON and how the resulting json looks like ? Also, are you sure you have included `jackson-databind` in maven ?